# How can I change the default location of Node Command prompt?

Tags: node.js

How can I change the default location of Node cmd to any desktop folders?
Currently, it's showing: "C:\Users\Sowmay>"

I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: Do you want to only access another location this time, or do you want it to become a default every time you type "node"?

Comment: Much better if you give ways to do both things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case, 
When you install nodejs, comes a private prompt, but you can also access the command prompt by typing "node".

If This Appear `>`, will work.

**Example:**

[image]

But, if you want access folder via **Windows**, I recommend you open your paste with the GUI and copy the folder path...

**Example - Paste X (Copy):**

[image]

**And paste in your Prompt command:**

```
cd paste your folder here //and type Enter
```

[image]

If you use **Linux**:

```
cd /etc/network/yourpaste
```

And if you can run some archive .js or other, you can use after you access the folder (X) with any file (server.js like example):

```
node server.js
```